# In a series of series, how to subtract every 1st number in each sub-series event from every nth number in those events?

Tags: r

I have multiple series of timepoints. Some series have five timepoints, others have ten or fifteen timepoints. The series are in multiples of five because the event I am measuring is always five timepoints long; some recordings have multiple events in succession. For instance:

Series 1:

1. **0**
2. 77
3. 98
4. 125
5. 174

Series 2:

1. **0**
2. 69
3. 95
4. 117
5. 179
6. **201**
7. 222
8. 246
9. 277
10. 293

0 marks the beginning of each series. Series 1 is a single event, but Series 2 is two events in succession. The 6th timepoint in Series 2 is the start of the second event in that series.

I have an R dataframe that contains every timepoint in one column:

```
dd <- data.frame(
  timepoint=c(0, 77, 98, 125, 174,
     0, 69, 95, 117, 179, 201, 222, 246, 277, 293)
)
```

I need to know the duration from the start of each *event* to the 4th timepoint in each event. For the above data, that means:

- Duration 1: 125 - 0 = 125
- Duration 2: 179 - 0 = 179
- Duration 3: 277 - 201 = 76

**How can I write a simple piece of R code that will tell me the duration of that interval regardless of how many series or events there are, i.e. regardless of how many numbers are in the column?**

I tried using diff() and seq_along(), but that seems only useful for every nth number, which doesn't work in this case.

```
diff(vec[seq_along(vec) %% 4 == 1])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is maybe one way to do it with dplyr. We break up the data into "runs" which reset at each 0 and them we have the "sequences" which reset each 5 values.

```
dd %>% 
  group_by(run =cumsum(timepoint==0)) %>% 
  mutate(seq = (row_number()-1) %/% 5 + 1) %>% 
  group_by(run, seq) %>% 
  summarize(diff=timepoint[4]-timepoint[1])
#     run   seq  diff
#   <int> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     1   125
# 2     2     1   117
# 3     2     2    76
```

It makes it somewhat easy to tie the value back to where it came from.

If you just wanted to use indexing, here's a helper function

```
diff4v1 <- function(x) {
  idx <- (seq_along(x)-1) %% 5+1;
  x[idx==4] - x[idx==1]
}

diff4v1(dd$timepoint)
# [1] 125 117  76
```

Comment: Oh wonderful, that helper function does indeed help! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is your data frame (hypothetical)

```
df = data.frame(series = round(rnorm(40, 100, 50)))
head(df)
  series
1     16
2     35
3     75
4    125
5    190
6     85
```

And these are your differences

```
idx = c(1:nrow(df))
df[which(idx %% 5 == 4), "series"] - df[which(idx %% 5 == 1), "series"]
[1]  109  -38 -101  -47   34  -52  -63   -5
```